# Struggling with flask request in pycharm community 404 bad request

Tags: python, flask, request, http-status-code-404

My terminal returns
`None /calculate_salary HTTP/0.9 HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST` - but in webpage it says 404 not found, the requested url was not found on the server if you entered the url manually check your spelling and try again."

```
import flask
from flask import *
from flask import render_template

from utilities import cc


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/helicopter')
def hello_world():
    return 'Heli, World!'


@app.route('/')
def salary_form_one():
    return render_template('index.html')



# This is where problem starts
@app.route('/calculate_salary,', methods=['POST'])
def calculate_salary():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # This variable named profession is = to the input for the form qustion named profession
        profession = int(request.form['profession'])
        number_of_expereince_years = int(request.form['experince'])
        languages = request.form['languages']
        user_coding_languages = languages.split()

        design_tools = request.form['designTools']
        users_design_tools = design_tools.split()

        dob = request.form['dob']
        full_name = request.form['FullName']
        age = request.form['age']

        country = request.form['country']
        state = request.form['state']
        number_of_education_years = request.form['educationYears']

        if int(profession) == 1:
            is_designer = False
        else:
            is_developer = False

        result_message = cc.calculate_expected_salarys(users_design_tools, state, languages, is_developer,
                                                       is_designer, dob, age, state)

        return flask.render_template("result.html", message=result_message)

    else:
        return 'please submit a post request'
```

**My guess is I didn't assign the route, but I don't know for sure.**

Comment: If it says 404 not found it likely means that you are not sending the post request to the right URL, double check you are sending it to something like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/calculate_salary,` (Notice the comma at the end of the URL in your code)

Comment: thanks @SleepyStew it was an issue but now ive got another.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can get a 404 if you get the HTTP method wrong in the request - your handler says that it only handles `POST` requests (`methods=["POST"]`). So, if you're making, say a `GET` request, you'll get a 404. This also means that your `if`/`else` checking the request method is redundant.

Comment: ok never mind my previous on http so i was playing with my code and i learnd the problem was acctully in the bit of code listing valuesin the function calculate salary also i deleted alll things specifying what request it takes thanks

Comment: Thanks turns out when i reloaded i get requested